# How to convert mktime() to a numeric date?

Tags: php, mktime

I have used mktime() function in my code. And it prints this: Feb-12-1998. I wanna convert this something like that: 02-12-1998. But in my language it has to be 12-02-1998. Im kind of confused. Some help would be great.

```
echo(date("M-d-Y",mktime(0,0,0,2,12,98))."<br />");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use following code :

```
echo(date("d-m-Y",mktime(0,0,0,2,12,98)));
```

output : 12-02-1998

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = 'Feb-12-1998';

echo date('m-d-Y',strtotime($date));

Output : 02-12-1998
```

Use this code

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
echo(date("m-d-Y",mktime(0,0,0,2,12,98))."<br />");
```

https://3v4l.org/vPKbW

see this: 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

i hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "M-d-Y" use "m-d-Y", it will gives you numeric date result;

Use Following code

```
echo date('m-d-Y',mktime(0,0,0,2,12,98)).'<br />';
```